# How to average together paths of varying length through popularity charts?

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

So basically, I'm looking at data from some music popularity charts. So I can see how many weeks a song was on the charts, what position it was in, what week it was in that position, and the song name and artist.

I have separated the charts to only contain the entries of songs that at some point become number one hits, and want to see the average "journey" of each song to the number one hit by decade.

Of course, some of these songs spent more time on the Top 100 charts overall. So while it would seem easy to simply average each position the song occupied, it can't be done so easily.

I thought about adding a number of dummy variables when a song was out of the top 100, something like 101, equal to the length of the the maximum number of weeks any track has spent on the charts. But that just seems like it would end up skewing my data.

My data looks like this (except with multiple tracks, and more entries than this for this particular song of course:

https://ethercalc.org/73oyih35ryu2

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, my solution is the following:

First of all, you can group the dataframe by song and add the numbers to a string as strings.

```
new_df=pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('Song')['Position'].apply(lambda x:' '.join(x.astype(str))))
```

It will return something like this :

```
                                   Position
Song                                       
Radioactive  93 98 45 56 45 45 45 1 4 67 89
```

Then I'm splitting the string by "1", I'm taking the first element and I'm adding to it the number '1'.

```
new_df['Position']=new_df['Position'].apply(lambda x:x.split('1')[0]+'1')
print(new_df)
                           Position
Song                               
Radioactive  93 98 45 56 45 45 45 1
```

After that, I can turn it into a list splitting with space and i can take the average of this list:

```
new_df['Position'].apply(lambda x: np.mean([int(i) for i in x.split()]))

print(new_df)

Song
Radioactive    53.5
```